# Change display property scrolls the page to it's top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with changing objects display property with Javascript.

I fill a table from data in a `mysql` database using `php`, and for each row it makes a `DIV` with `display:none` property as I want, and I have a simple JavaScript function to show/hide the `div`.
Here is `css` for `div` :

```
display:none; /*initially menu item is hidden*/
position: absolute; /*absolute positioning to float*/
background-color:#fff;
width:230px;
min-height:120px;
right:60px;
border:5px solid #ccc;
text-align:right;
direction:rtl;
padding:10px;
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

and this is the javascript :

```
function showfield (a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.display = "block";  
}
function hidefield (a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.display = "none";  
}
```

The function works and divs show at the place they must, but the problem is :

when I call the JavaScript function to show, it shows the div but the page scrolls to its top and for seeing the opened div I should scroll down, as my page is a report page it may be a long long page and this is not a good happening at all!

I can't understand why its happens and is there a way to prevent this auto scrolling?

Comment: let me guess.... u called your `showfield` function in `<a>` tag... like...`<a href="#" onclick="showfield()"`>.. is it????

Comment: hi can you please write html code here.

Comment: @bipen Yes i called it in a <a> tag as you say

Comment: @Praveenkalal  <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#<?php echo("a".$cntr); ?>" onclick="showfield(<?php echo($cntr); ?>)"><?php echo($cntr); ?></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below code its working for me.

```
<script>
 function showfield(a)
  {
    document.getElementById(a).style.display = "block";  
  }
   function hidefield(a)
  {
      alert(a);
    document.getElementById(a).style.display = "none";  
  }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showfield('myid')">show</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hidefield('myid');">hide</a>

<div id="myid">test content goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this thn....

**HTMl**

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#<?php echo("a".$cntr); ?>" onclick="return showfield(<?php echo($cntr); ?>)"><?php echo($cntr); ?></a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showfield(a){
   document.getElementById(a).style.display = "block";
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it dosnt help , the solution was : href="#javascript:void(0)"
i used href="#<?php echo("a".$cntr); ?>" before to go to A tags because i couldnt find the way, thats not neccesary at all

Answer (score 0):

Javascript void didn't work for me.

My solution: try giving your button or  the href="#mybutton" and id="mybutton". So the page will jump to the button (you can do this for the field too). If you give it href="#" it will jump to the top of the page. And href="" will reload the page and undo the function.